# How to count the commas in text field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I want a formula field that should contain the count based on commas **(',')**

Example:

if if text filed contains value1,value2 then count should be 1

if if text filed contains value1,value2,value3 then count should be 2

I am unable to get this formula field. Please help me how can i achieve this formula field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LEN(Text_Field__c ) - LEN( SUBSTITUTE(Text_Field__c , ',', '') )
```

Comment: Hi Saumya, That's great. Its working 
But i have doubt,  i tried upto 10 commas....  will it work for irrespective number of commas?

Comment: @KSKumaar, It would work. have you tried it?

Comment: @KSKumaar Yes, it will.

Comment: Yes @Rahul Shrma, Its working

Comment: This answer would be better if you included a description of why this works. Code dumps without explanation won't really help people that view this answer unless they have the _exact same problem to be solved_. Simply providing the answer on a silver platter doesn't help the person who asked the question grow more independent as a programmer either.

Comment: @KSKumaar Blindly using code that you don't understand can be dangerous. I would suggest that, instead of just plugging this formula in to your org and calling it a day, you try to work out in your mind how it actually works. If you can do that, you'll better understand the potential limitations (and you won't need to manually test every single case).